# How to detect programmatically if you app is maximized in chromebook?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-screen-support, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

I am porting my app to Chromebook as Google has announced for Android support in ChromeOS. I am struggling with a problem where I am getting system toast message "This app may not work when resized".

My question is simple:

*a) how to detect programmatically when my app is re-sized in chromebook?*

*b) how to remove this toast message in chromebook*

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: "how to detect programmatically when my app is re-sized in chromebook?" -- it is a configuration change, the same as when a phone or tablet's screen is rotated, etc. "how to remove this toast message in chromebook" -- I have not seen that message on Chrome OS yet. It is a common message on Android 7.0, meaning that the app's `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or lower.

Comment: but my targetSDKVersion is 24 and I am not getting any message in Android 7 but when my app runs in Chromebook and some how it got re-sized to protrait from maximum size, system shows this toast message.